Diagonal of non-$L¹$-measurable set is non-$L²$-measurable
I am working on a problem in measure theory, Lebesgue measure:
I should show that if a set $A\subset [0, 1]$ is not $L¹$-measurable then the set $B:=\{(x, x)| x \in A\}$ is not $L²$-measurable.
My idea is to say that if $B$ were measurable, then $\forall C\subset \mathbb{R} : L²(C)=L²(C\cap B)+L²(C\setminus B)$ then somehow projecting this onto $A$ but cannot work it through. Can somebody help or is there a more elegant way to do this?
Can I use the canonical projection from $B$ onto $A$ being continuous somehow?

Wouldn't a collection of rectangles (actually squares with opposite vertices on the diagonal) for an inner measure of $B$ project onto a collection of intervals for an inner measure of $A$, and likewise for outer measures?  And if the inner and outer areas were equal?...

@EricTowers thank you for your fast reply, I don't quite get it though.. Do you mean I can use continuity of the projection, and subspace topology somehow? I'm not sure how these topological arguments apply to algebras

Assuming that $L^1$-measurable refers to Lebesgue measure on the line and $L^2$-measurable refers to Lebesgue measure on the plane, this is false. The whole diagonal ${(x,x):x\in\mathbb R}$ is $L^2$-measurable with measure zero, and therefore so is its subsst $B$.

@AndreasBlass thank you, but the subset B need not be measurable just because the diagonal $\Delta$ is (think $A$ a vitali set), so what other arguments can we use? or is there a counterexample where $B \subset \Delta$ is measurable but $A$ isn't?

@arridadiyaat If a set has measure zero, then so do all its subsets.
